# How to add a second level column header/index to dataframe by matching to dictionary values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe.

```
l1 | a    b    c  |  d    e    f
--------------------------------
0  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
1  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
2  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
```

And this dictionary.

```
{
  "a": "dog",
  "b": "dog",
  "c": "dog",
  "d": "fish",
  "e": "fish",
  "f": "fish",
}
```

What is the simplest way to create a second column level matching the existing columns to their category from the dictionary?

*The real columns and dictionary are much bigger and less organized.*

The result should look like this.

```
l2 |     dog      |     fish
l1 | a    b    c  |  d    e    f
--------------------------------
0  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
1  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
2  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra mapping for the first series, then use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
d.update({'l1': 'l2'})
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d[k], k) for k in df.columns])

print(df)

  l2 dog       fish      
  l1   a  b  c    d  e  f
0  0   1  1  1    1  1  1
1  1   1  1  1    1  1  1
2  2   1  1  1    1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jpp. I can't get it to work, sorry. In `d.update({'l1': 'l2'})` what is `d`? A new dataframe? Also, is `{'l1': 'l2'}` the dictionary in my example or literally `{'l1': 'l2'}`?

Comment: `d` is your input dictionary... `d = {
  "a": "dog",
...
  "f": "fish",
}`; You can take this literally: `d.update({'l1': 'l2'})` because your first series is labelled `'l1'` and your output has this under `'l2'`.

Comment: finding a alt :-)

Answer (score 1):

Different method from `groupby` and `concat` since you already have the mapper

```
d['l1']='l2'

pd.concat(dict(tuple(df.groupby(d,axis=1))),1)#From jpp more succinct 
  dog       fish       l2
    a  b  c    d  e  f l1
0   1  1  1    1  1  1  0
1   1  1  1    1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1    1  1  1  2
```

---

```
d={
  "a": "dog",
  "b": "dog",
  "c": "dog",
  "d": "fish",
  "e": "fish",
  "f": "fish",
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `pd.concat` :)

Comment: @jpp the way you are using definitely is more straight forward  for this type of problem .

Comment: Yup certainly performance-wise OP should just rename columns.. this is splitting stuff out and putting it back together again. Still syntactically beautiful :)