# Pandas add a second level index to the columns using a list

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with column headings (and for my real data multi-level row indexes).  I want to add a second level index to the columns based on a list I have.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"apple": [7,5,6,4,7,5,8,6],
       "strawberry": [3,5,2,1,3,0,4,2],
       "banana": [1,2,1,2,2,2,1,3],
        "chocolate" : [5,8,4,2,1,6,4,5],
        "cake":[4,4,5,1,3,0,0,3]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
food_cat = ["fv","fv","fv","j","j"]
```

I am wanting something that looks like this:

[image: example desired output]

I tried to use [How to add a second level column header/index to dataframe by matching to dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53861225/2613271) - however couldn't get it working (and not ideal as I'd need to figure out how to automate the dictionary, which I don't have).

I also tried adding the list as a row in the dataframe and converting that row to a second level index as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678238/2613271) using

```
df.loc[len(df)] = food_cat
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.columns, df.iloc[len(df)-1])
```

but got the error
*Check if lengths of all arrays are equal or not,
TypeError: Input must be a list / sequence of array-likes.*

I also tried using `df = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.columns, np.array(food_cat))` with `import numpy as np` but got the same error.

I feel like this should be a simple task (it is for rows), and there are a lot of questions asked, but I was struggling to find something I could duplicate to adapt to my data.

Comment: why not just use : ``df.columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([food_cat, df.columns])``

Comment: [pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas-multiindex-from-arrays)  the first parameter, `arrays` is a *list* of 1d "array-like" objects.

Comment: thanks @sammywemmy if you post that as an answer I will accept.  I spent a couple hours trying to find a working example before I gave up and posted.  I am unsurprised that it really was simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas multi index creation requires a list(or list like) passed as an argument:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([food_cat, df.columns])

df

     fv                           j
  apple strawberry banana chocolate cake
0     7          3      1         5    4
1     5          5      2         8    4
2     6          2      1         4    5
3     4          1      2         2    1
4     7          3      2         1    3
5     5          0      2         6    0
6     8          4      1         4    0
7     6          2      3         5    3
```

Comment: Can i specify on the columns that I want to apply the multi index for? In the example give, how do i apply `fv` only for the `banana` and `chocolate` columns?

Comment: @thentangler kindly create a new question, with a clear example of your expected output dataframe. You can tag me when you post the question.